# Next.js App Router triggers a page reload when clicking back on browser (web migrated from CRA)

Tags: next.js, app-router

We've migrated a CRA web to Next.js. We initially did it using pages router, and has been working fine. Now we're trying to migrate to App router, and we've found this issue.

1. If we click on links (still react-router links), we move between pages correctly.
2. If you reload, click on a link to go to another section and then click back on the browser, it works correctly.
3. If you reload, click on a link to go to another section, then go to another section and then click back on the browser, it goes back for less than a second and then triggers full a page reload.

For changing to App Router we have a very basic configuration:

/src/app/layout:

```
import type { ReactNode } from 'react';

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

/src/app/[[...app]]/page.tsx

```
'use client';

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import '../../index.css';

const CreateReactAppEntryPoint = dynamic(() => import('containers/Root'), {
  ssr: false,
});

function Page() {
  return <CreateReactAppEntryPoint />;
}

export default Page;
```

The equivalent approach with pages routes works correctly.